# Android design xml player

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

Iam trying to make a design which I cant figure how to fix it. What I want is to make something similar to this one : http://i57.tinypic.com/2v8n5z9.jpg

I have tried somestuff (relativelayout) which didnt solve my question. is there someone can explain me how to do it?

I have this one so far but I its not like how I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/content_bg" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    layout="@layout/header" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/footer" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/Seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:max="100" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Seekbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/play_start" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit, I fixed it by myself**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/content_bg" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    layout="@layout/header" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/footer" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/Seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:max="100" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Seekbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/play_start" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/include2"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Supposed to add more layout in layouts, added solution to answer

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout seems to fit better your needs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/include2"
    layout="@layout/header" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/play_start" />

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/Seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:max="100" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    layout="@layout/footer" />
```

Just set the margins as you want to make it look the way you want